# ¿Cómo utilizar múltiples onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android

En mi actividad trato de leer un código de barras mediante la librería `Zxing` y por otra parte trato de capturar 4 fotografías. He tenido problemas en el momento de capturar las fotografías y regresar a mi actividad: se me detiene la aplicación. Me he preguntado si el problema es porque ocupo dos acciones que recaen en el método `onActivityResult` y quisiera saber como separarlo ya que cuando tomo la tercera o segunda fotografía me marca error y no me permite terminar capturar las 4 ¿Cómo separo el resultado de la lectura y la de la captura de fotografías?

```
 public void addRight(View button)
{
   if(capturas<=3) {
       if(capturas==0){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tome imagen FRONTAL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       else if(capturas==1){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tome imagen TRASERA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       else if(capturas==2){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tome imagen IZQUIERDA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       else if(capturas==3){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tome imagen DERECHA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       int code = TAKE_PICTURE;
       startActivityForResult(intent, code);

   }else {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No puede tomar mas de 4 fotografias",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    contentTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
    layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content);
    scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView5);

  try {
        //------------------CÓDIGO DE BARRAS------------------------
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            //Quiere decir que se obtuvo resultado pro lo tanto:
            //Desplegamos en pantalla el contenido del código de barra scaneado
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            contentTxt.setText(scanContent);
            //Desplegamos en pantalla el nombre del formato del código de barra scaneado
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            formatTxt.setText(scanFormat);
            capturas_scan = capturas_scan +1;
        }
        if (scanningResult == null) {
            //Quiere decir que NO se obtuvo resultado

            if (capturas_scan == 2) {
                capturas_scan = capturas_scan - 1;
            }
            else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No se ha recibido datos del scaneo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        //-------------------FOTOGRAFIA-------------------------
      if (capturas_scan == 1 || capturas_scan == 2) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            int id = R.layout.layout_right;
            LinearLayout relativeLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            params.topMargin = 50;
            relativeLayout.setPadding(5, 3, 5, 3);
            //relativeLayout.setPadding(5, 3, 5, 3);
            relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

            /**
             * Se revisa si la imagen viene de la c‡mara (TAKE_PICTURE) o de la galer’a (SELECT_PICTURE)
             */

            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                /**
                 * Si se reciben datos en el intent tenemos una vista previa (thumbnail)
                 */
                if (data != null) {
                    /**
                     * En el caso de una vista previa, obtenemos el extra ÒdataÓ del intent y
                     * lo mostramos en el ImageView
                     */
                    try {


                        if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                            iv = (ImageView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
                            iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("data"));
                            BitmapDrawable estirable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
                            Bitmap bitmap = estirable.getBitmap();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 5, bos);
                            byte[] bb = bos.toByteArray();
                            image = Base64.encodeToString(bb, Base64.NO_WRAP);
                            if (capturas == 0) {
                                v.add(0, image);
                            } else {
                                v.add(capturas, image);
                            }
                            layout.addView(relativeLayout);

                            scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1. Hubo un error al tomar la fotografía." + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    /**
                     * De lo contrario es una imagen completa
                     */
                } else {
                    /**
                     * A partir del nombre del archivo ya definido lo buscamos y creamos el bitmap
                     * para el ImageView
                     */
                    iv = (ImageView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(name));

                }
                /**
                 * Recibimos el URI de la imagen y construimos un Bitmap a partir de un stream de Bytes
                 */
                capturas = capturas + 1;

            }else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                InputStream is;
                try {
                    is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2.Hubo un error al tomar la fotografía.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
      else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"3.Hubo un error al tomar las fotografías.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  }catch (Exception e){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ha habido un error"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Carlos, agrega el error que te muestra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo debes de validar en base al `requestCode` por ejemplo si vas a agregar fotos 
puedes definir dos constantes diferentes:

```
private static final int AGREGA_FOTO = 0;
private static final int LEER_CODIGO = 1;
```

al realizar las operaciones envía el `requestCode` dependiendo de la operación:

Agrega fotos:

```
 startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, AGREGA_FOTO);
```

Lee codigo de barras:

```
  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, LEER_CODIGO);
```

en `onActivityResult()` se realiza la validación :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == AGREGA_FOTO  && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
    //Agrega fotos.
    }else if(requestCode == LEER_CODIGO  && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    //Lee código de barras.
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió y es justo lo que buscaba :D

Comment: Excellente Carlos!, Saludos!