# Cancelar PICK_NUMBER manejar error

Tags: android, android-studio, numberpicker

Con este código hago que se rellene un editText seleccionando un contacto de entre todos los de la agenda.

```
 con1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.con1);

 con1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_NUMBER);
 }});

     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (requestCode == PICK_NUMBER){
                Uri contactUri = data.getData();
    
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
    
                int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(column);
    
                if(phoneNumber != null)
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.trim();
    
                if(phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.equals("")) {
                    // This should never happen, but just in case we'll handle it
                    return;
                }
    
                // Retrieve the contact name.
                column = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Identity.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String name = cursor.getString(column);
    
                con1.setText(phoneNumber+" - "+name);
               
                cursor.close();         

  }
    }
```

La selección funciona perfectamente, pero si se pulsa en el editText, se abre la agenda, Y NO SE SELCCIONA CONTACTO, lanza el siguiente error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity
> {midlab.ap/midlab.ap.NBas}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3406)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at midlab.ap.NBas.onActivityResult(NBas.java:491)
> at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5472)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3402)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
> at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Tengo claro que tengo que manejar el error en:

```
 if(phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.equals("")) {
                // This should never happen, but just in case we'll handle it
                return;
            }
```

pero no sé que poner, no se si hay que hacer cancel(), dismiss() o algo similar.

¿Alguien sabe cómo manejar este error?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿phoneNumber es un String?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo sí

Comment: Cual es la linea 491 de NBas.java ?

Comment: @Jorgesys Uri contactUri = data.getData();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se especifica aquí:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
> midlab.ap.NBas.onActivityResult(NBas.java:491)

en la linea:

```
Uri contactUri = data.getData();
```

este es un error común, se trata de obtener información cuando el bundle que se recibe tiene valor null, ya sea en `onCreate()` de una Activity o en `onActivityResult()` , se tiene que validar que el bundle sea diferente a null.

En el caso de [`onActivityResult()` lo correcto es validar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15127/95) usando la constante: [RESULT_OK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#RESULT_OK)

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
```

ya que esta indica una operación exitosa.

```
     @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_NUMBER){ //*validación
                Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            ...
            ...
            ... 

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado con esto:  `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)`

Hay que poner este if justo despues de este otro: `if (requestCode == PICK_NUMBER)`

Así quedaría:

```
     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
            if (requestCode == PICK_NUMBER){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactUri = data.getData();
    
                    // Perform the query.
                    // We don't need a selection or sort order (there's only one result for the given URI)
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ...

}
```